# MacOS Mountain Lion Mercurial postreview:

Tags: mercurial

I am issuing the following command:

hg postreview -o -e 4714 tip --debug

with this result:

using http://....
sending capabilities command
abort: repository 'http://...' is not local

(I shortened the URLs, the url is the right one)

This error does not seem to originate in the postreview extension, but I can not figure out what the problem is. Does someone know?

Thanks. Chris

=============
System:

I have OS X 10.8 (12A269) installed
Python: Python 2.7.2 [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible ..

Installed mercurial through mercurial-2.3+20120807-py2.7-macosx10.8.mpkg which was downloaded from http://mercurial.berkwood.com/

I use the extension postreview: https://code.google.com/p/mercurial-reviewboard/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem since mercurial 2.3

I have updated my clone of mercurial reviewboard plugin to fix it here:
https://bitbucket.org/windix/mercurial-reviewboard/

Note that, this is not the official mercurial reviewboard plugin (which is at http://code.google.com/p/mercurial-reviewboard/). The one I am using is with outogoing support (so you can send all the outgoing changesets for review at once).

There has been an issue submitted to the official one here:
http://code.google.com/p/mercurial-reviewboard/issues/detail?id=48

so hopefully someone will fix it there